# How to prove by definition (epsilon-delta) this limit of 2 variables?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I have this limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,0)}x^2\cos(y)=1$$
How to prove by definition:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,0)}x^2\cos(y)=L\Longleftrightarrow\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0\ \big[ 0<\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-0)^2}<\delta\Rightarrow |x^2\cos(y)-1|<\varepsilon \big]$$
The trigonometric function is difficulting the usual computation of factoring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint*: Try writing

$$|x^2\cos y - 1| \leq |x^2\cos y - \cos y| + |\cos y - 1|$$
$$  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \leq |x^2 - 1|  + |\cos y - 1|$$

---

Added:

The logic is the other way around: as $\cos y$ and $x^2$ are continuous, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta_1, \delta_2 > 0$ such that

$$0 < |x - 1| < \delta_1 \ \Longrightarrow \ | x^2 - 1 | < \epsilon/2$$
and

$$ 0 < |y| < \delta_2 \ \Longrightarrow \ |  \cos y - 1 | < \epsilon/2$$

Hence given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$, then

$$ \| (x,y) - (1,0) \| = \sqrt{ (x-1)^2 + y^2 } < \delta \ \Rightarrow 0 < |x - 1| < \delta \ \wedge 0 < |y| < \delta \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

$$ \ \ \ \ \ \  \  \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \     \Rightarrow 0 < |x - 1| < \delta_1 \ \wedge 0 < |y| < \delta_2 $$

$$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \     \Rightarrow |x^2\cos y - 1| \leq  |x^2 - 1|  + |\cos y - 1| $$

$$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon $$

Comment: I have to do $\big|x^2-1\big|+\big|\cos(y)-1\big|<\varepsilon$ then $\big|x^2-1\big|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\wedge \big|\cos(y)-1\big|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

Comment: See added comment above

Comment: Hmmm... I got the idea but I don't know how to justify those steps. I'm trying to understand the reasoning more than solve the limit and I couldn't find examples like this one, with polynomials and trigonometric functions

Comment: I assume you're good down to the point where I choose $\delta$. First implication: because $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \leq |a|$ or $|b|$ ... 

Second implication: $\delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2) \leq \delta_1$ or $\delta_2$ by definition of $\min$ ...

Third implication: the original inequality above; and then the choice of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ given the continuity of $x^2$ and $\cos y$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $|x^2\cos(y)-1|$ as:

$$|x^2\cos(y)-1|=|(x^2-1)(\cos(y)-1)+x^2-1+\cos(y)-1| \leq \\ \leq  |(x^2-1)||(\cos(y)-1)|+|x^2-1|+|\cos(y)-1|$$

Now you can write single variable delta-epsilon proof for $x^2-1$ and $\cos(y)-1$.

Comment: how I can be sure that $\big|(x^2-1)(\cos(y)-1)\big|+\big|x^2-1\big|+\big|\cos(y)-1\big|$ is lower than $\varepsilon$?

Comment: If $|(x,y)-(1,0)|<\delta$, then also $|x-1|<\delta$ and $|y-0|<\delta$. You know that one variable function $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(y)=\cos(y)$ are continous, so exists $\delta>0$ that when $|x-1|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon/3$ the same for $g$.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm an amateur in this kind of problems. I thought that those two variable limits should be done differently and I don't get your suggestion